# How to set "default option" in "options_from_collection_for_select" (Rails 3.2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, select

I'm trying to put default option of @languages -  'All Languages'
Here is view:

```
.dropdown-search-filter
   = select_tag "languages", options_from_collection_for_select(@languages, "id", "to_label", selected: params[:languages]), prompt: "All Languages"
.dropdown-search-filter.search-select-tag
   = select_tag "destination", content_tag(:option,'All Destinations',:value=>"all")+options_from_collection_for_select(@destinations, "id", "name", selected: params[:destination])
```

It still puts English as a default:  [here screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s87/sh/0145d063-1a55-4852-981f-778ca6912cb0/cf2a6b68294fcedcd7dec47ad346bf4f).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is params[:languages] ?

Comment: @NikitaSingh  In controller: "language_id = params[:languages].blank? ? Language.all.map {|l| l.id} : params[:languages] rescue 1". Can it help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access params in view which you can not. Make an instance variable like @language_id and use it in the view

Answer (score 0):

As I can read in the documentation ([link](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)), something like:

```
select_tag "languages", options_from_collection_for_select(@languages, "id", "to_label", params[:languages]), prompt: "All Languages"
```

Note that `params[:languages]` must be a valid id of your languages collection, because the fourth parameter (default selection) is based on the id's of the options (the field named in the second parameter).

Does this work for you?

Comment: Still brings "en", because in controller set "language_id = params[:languages].blank? ? Language.all.map {|l| l.id} : params[:languages] rescue 1". "En" has id = 1.

Comment: I can´t understand your example. What I tries to explain is that params[:language] needs to be a valid "id" of a language object in @languages.